# Angular 2 - File Upload

Tags: csv, angular

I am trying to upload a csv/xlxs file in angular 2 but whenever i submit the file, i get an error. please try again from my backend although it works fine on postman. What could be wrong in my file service ?

```
//error
 <b>Warning</b>: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />

    //service
        constructor (private authenticate:AuthenticationService) {
                this.filetrack = Observable.create(observer => {
                    this.progressObserver = observer
                }).share();
            }

             SendRequest (url: string, params: string[], files: File[]) {
                return Observable.create(observer => {
                    let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                        xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
                    }

                    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                                observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                                observer.complete();
                            } else {
                                observer.error(xhr.response);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {

                        this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                        this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
                    };


                    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authenticate.user_token);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

                    xhr.send(formData);


                });
            }
        }

    //component
    export class FileUploadComponent {
        constructor(private service:FileUploadService) {
            this.service.filetrack.subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log('progress = '+data);
                });
        }

        onChange(event) {
            console.log('onChange');
             let files = event.target.files;
            console.log(files);
            this.service.SendRequest('http://localhost:8000/register/v1/file/country', [], files).subscribe(() => {
                console.log('sent');
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @MarcosMaia   <b>Warning</b>: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
this is the error in the console

Comment: this might be helpful as you can also take a look at their implementation if you want: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload

Comment: @MarcosMaia, i was having lot of challenges trying to implement valor software file upload with my backend. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: any help here people?